# Bootstrap popover semi-manual toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have an element

```
<span id="1">Element</span>
```

and made it as popover enabled element by initializing bootstrap popover using javascript

```
  $('#how2').popover({
     html:true,
     placement:"right",
     trigger:"click",
     content:"somecontent",
     title:"sometitle",        
    });
```

Then in "somecontent", I have a `<script></script>` whose content is

```
$(".popover-close-button").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //remove the .popover element
});
```

whose function is giving a click listener to a X (close) button defined in "sometitle" to remove the whole ".popover" element created.

Toggle works. If `id="1"` element is clicked, it shows the popover. When it is clicked again, popover hides. The problem comes when the X button is clicked. The popover does hide (removed actually), but, when `id="1"` element is clicked to make the popover shows up, nothing happens. A popover will only shows up at the **second click**.

I will be happy to know why such thing happens. Does bootstrap make use of global javascript variable to determine the on/off status of the popover?

Note: `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` is chosen over `$("#1").popover("hide")` for a DRY purpose. The content loaded inside popover is expected to be used in other places also. Therefore, putting "#1" there, is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

try

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(".popover-close-button").click(function(){
      $(this).closest('.popover').remove(); //remove the .popover element
});
```

or

[.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$(".popover-close-button").click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.popover').remove(); //remove the .popover element
});
```

Comment: Both works in removing the popover (make it disappear), but to make it appear again, still 2 clicks needed. The problem only happens if the popover closed using X button. If the popover is closed by re-clicking in popover enabled element, it works perfectly.

Comment: @YudhoAhmadDiponegoro can you make fiddle ?

Comment: Okay. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/wongsolo/79Yj6/2/ However, I could not incorporate bootstrap with jsfiddle. So the popover does not work there, it is just the code.

Comment: @YudhoAhmadDiponegoro .popover JavaScript file ?

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Oh it is in the bootstrap.js. I will extract it and put it there

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $(elem).popover(destroy);

```
$('.popover-close-button').click(function() {
    $('#how2').popover('destroy');
});
```

This removes the popover all together so that it won't be able to be triggered by another click.

See the docs here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Answer (score 0):

### Add these libraries

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

### Code For Pop over

```
<div class="container">
     <a href="#" title="Dismissible popover" data-toggle="popover"   data-trigger="focus" data-content="Click anywhere in the document to close this popover">Click me</a>
</div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```